# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Im writing a project with flask (for python) and when I run from the pycharm the project (which included html files), it gives me the following error:

[image]

the error is about line 192 in home.html...

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'

And... this is the html file, that makes problems :-(

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/stylish-portfolio.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body id="page-top">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <a class="menu-toggle rounded" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-nav-item">
          <a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="masthead d-flex">
      <div class="container text-center my-auto">
        <h1 class="mb-1">Timely</h1>
        <h3 class="mb-5">
          <em>A Free Time Management App</em>
        </h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Find Out More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </header>

    <!-- About -->
    <section class="content-section bg-light" id="about">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
            <h2>Stylish Portfolio is the perfect theme for your next project!</h2>
            <p class="lead mb-5">This theme features a flexible, UX friendly sidebar menu and stock photos from our friends at
              <a href="https://unsplash.com/">Unsplash</a>!</p>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">What We Offer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Services -->
    <section class="content-section bg-primary text-white text-center" id="services">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content-section-heading">
          <h3 class="text-secondary mb-0">Services</h3>
          <h2 class="mb-5">What We Offer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <span class="service-icon rounded-circle mx-auto mb-3">
              <i class="icon-screen-smartphone"></i>
            </span>
            <h4>
              <strong>Responsive</strong>
            </h4>
            <p class="text-faded mb-0">Looks great on any screen size!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
            <span class="service-icon rounded-circle mx-auto mb-3">
              <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
            </span>
            <h4>
              <strong>Redesigned</strong>
            </h4>
            <p class="text-faded mb-0">Freshly redesigned for Bootstrap 4.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-md-0">
            <span class="service-icon rounded-circle mx-auto mb-3">
              <i class="icon-like"></i>
            </span>
            <h4>
              <strong>Favorited</strong>
            </h4>
            <p class="text-faded mb-0">Millions of users
              <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
              Start Bootstrap!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <span class="service-icon rounded-circle mx-auto mb-3">
              <i class="icon-mustache"></i>
            </span>
            <h4>
              <strong>Question</strong>
            </h4>
            <p class="text-faded mb-0">I mustache you a question...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Callout -->
    <section class="callout">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <h2 class="mx-auto mb-5">Welcome to
          <em>your</em>
          next website!</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" href="https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/stylish-portfolio/">Download Now!</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Call to Action -->
    <section class="content-section bg-primary text-white">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <h2 class="mb-4">The buttons below are impossible to resist...</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xl btn-light mr-4">Click Me!</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xl btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Map -->
    <section id="contact" c0lass="map">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
      <br/>
      <small>
        <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
      </small>
    </section>
0
    <!-- Footer -->
   <footer class="footer text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-inline mb-5">
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a class="social-link rounded-circle text-white mr-3" href="#">
              <i class="icon-social-facebook"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a class="social-link rounded-circle text-white mr-3" href="#">
              <i class="icon-social-twitter"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <a class="social-link rounded-circle text-white" href="#">
              <i class="icon-social-github"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-muted small mb-0">Copyright &copy; Taeer Mayzels</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/stylish-portfolio.min.js') }}"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Also, the files in the project ordered so:
[image]

I couldn't understand what the problem is, so I hope that one of the genius here can expose my error.

Comment: You should copy and paste the error as text instead of as an external image. Sometimes external resources disappear and thus the question would lack a lot of context and might cease to be useful for other people.

Answer (score 13):

Near the end of your code,

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
```

You missed a `'`, a `)`, and a `}}`

Answer (score 3):

Go through the call stack and look when the stack changes from a call to **jinja2** vs a call to one of your **HTML** pages, eg:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\DEV\a-flask\base\templates\base.html", line 55, in template
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1005, in render
    return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))
```

I went to line 55 in base.html:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-ui.min.js }}"></script>
```

The fix was to include the last quote and missing bracket:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is in syntax of 'url_for' function.

Check for the ' ' marks and filenames.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

change the above code to this-

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `" "` to `' '`.

This one doesn't work:
`{{ post["title"] }}`

This one should work:
`{{ post['title'] }}`